# Hide scroll bar for search filter and show only for mat-option in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material, scrollbar

I want to hide the scroll bar for `mat-select-filter` and show only for `mat-option` in Angular .

In AppComponent.html

```
<mat-form-field class="input-permissions">
    <mat-select
      placeholder="Permissions"
      multiple
      [formControl]="permissionsControl"
      disableOptionCentering
    >
      <mat-select-filter
        [placeholder]="'Search Permissions'"
        [array]="permissions"
        (filteredReturn)="filteredList = $event"
        [displayMember]="'appPermissions'"
        [showSpinner]="false"
      >
      </mat-select-filter>
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let permission of permissions"
        [value]="permission.value"
      >
        {{ permission.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Now it is showing like this,

[image: The scroll bar right now]

I want to show the scroll bar like this,

[image: The scroll bar I want]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using virtual scroll inside mat-select for mat-option in Angular.
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Answer (score 0):

The dynamite solution is to use `position:sticky` and `z-index` properties. You can try adding the following CSS to the item you want to stay fixed while the items below it are scrollable:

```
.class-name {
    top: 0px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
}
```